# why equality check not work in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I make a simple demo of xslt. I want to print `video_urls` tag value whose rate is `25`. I add for each loop in outer tag and get tag value?

Сan I add nested `foreach` loop to get url whose rate is `25`?

Here is my source XML:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <urls>
        <video_urls rate ="25">
            abccc
        </video_urls>
         <video_urls rate ="30">
            sdfsdf
        </video_urls>
    </urls>
  </cd>

  <cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
 <video_urls rate ="25">
            123nnn
        </video_urls>
         <video_urls rate ="30">
            pppppp
        </video_urls>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="urls/video_urls/@rate='25'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**expected output**

```
Empire Burlesque
abccc
Unchain my heart
123nnn
```

Comment: remove jquery tag from question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access only those values which having specific attribute values as follows,

You are trying to access the attribute incorrectly,

```
 urls/video_urls/@rate= "25"
```

Instead it should be access and checked,

```
 urls/video_urls[@rate = 25]
```

Your XML was also not consistent with nodes hence template does not gives you required expected answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
         <xsl:for-each select="cd">
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="urls/video_urls[@rate = 25]"/>

         </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

You need to fix your XML also for consistency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <urls>
        <video_urls rate ="25">
            abccc
        </video_urls>
         <video_urls rate ="30">
            sdfsdf
        </video_urls>
    </urls>
  </cd>

  <cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
    <urls>
        <video_urls rate ="25">
            123nnn
        </video_urls>
         <video_urls rate ="30">
            pppppp
        </video_urls>
    </urls>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Updated link : http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPs/3

Comment: it it not expected result..please see expected result

Comment: please see expected output ..!!

Comment: @user944513 try updaed answer. Your XML was incorrect. Second node was not having urls element.